# How to get a bootstrap dropdown to be visible beyond it's parent component? Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular project and within my project I have a header in my 'toolbar' component at the top. Within it, I have a dropdown menu component. I'm using Angular 5 and bootstrap to build my dropdown.

The problem is, the header within 'toolbar' is set to be only 100px high, and when the dropdown needs to be taller, it won't display past the bottom of the header, which is from the dropdown's parent component.

toolbar.component.html

```
<header>
    <div id="header-logo">
       <img id="header-img" [src]="fullImagePath">
    </div>
    <div id="selector">  
       <p>All Sites</p> 

       <app-dropdown></app-dropdown>

    </div>
</header>
```

toolbar.component.css

```
 header {
    height: 100px;
 }
```

dropdown.component.ts

```
  <li class="dropdown" dropdown> <!-- {1} -->
      <a dropdownToggle role="button"> <!-- {2} -->
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"> <!-- {3} -->
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
```

dropdown.component.css

```
li {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

What might I be able to add or change so that the dropdown can extend downward beyond the height of the header in the toolbar, 100px?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz showing the problem?

Comment: So here's the stackbitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5lkmyb but oddly enough it doesn't replicate the problem, here it is while I work on that

Comment: Your application may behave like [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heikvs). You can try setting `overflow: visible` for the `header` CSS style. Maybe an external style causes the overflow to be hidden. You could check if it is the case by inspecting the header control in the developement tool (F12).

Comment: This is exactly what happened! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. :-)